# cnn not working for deep network with 5 convolutional layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
def create_model(depth):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 130, 1)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

    for _ in range(depth):  
        model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


    return model
```

it is returning an error when depth is given 5 or more

```
model=create_model(5)
```

```
{
    "name": "ValueError",
    "message": "Exception encountered when calling layer \"conv2d_224\" (type Conv2D).

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node conv2d_224/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format=\"NHWC\", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding=\"VALID\", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_224/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,2,2,64], [3,3,64,64].

Call arguments received by layer \"conv2d_224\" (type Conv2D):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2, 2, 64), dtype=float32)",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 model=create_model(5)

Cell In[4], line 7, in create_model(depth)
      4 model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
      6 for _ in range(depth):  # Reduce the number of max pooling layers
----> 7     model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
      8     model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
     10 model.add(layers.Flatten())

File ~/tensorflow-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py:204, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.<locals>._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    202 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    203 try:
--> 204   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    205 finally:
    206   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File ~/tensorflow-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/tensorflow-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1751, in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def, extract_traceback)
   1748   c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1749 except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1750   # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1751   raise ValueError(e.message)
   1753 # Record the current Python stack trace as the creating stacktrace of this
   1754 # TF_Operation.
   1755 if extract_traceback:

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer \"conv2d_224\" (type Conv2D).

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node conv2d_224/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format=\"NHWC\", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding=\"VALID\", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_224/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,2,2,64], [3,3,64,64].

Call arguments received by layer \"conv2d_224\" (type Conv2D):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2, 2, 64), dtype=float32)"
}
```

when i am making a network for depth less than 5 then there is no error but i is happening for value 5 and more and i am not able to understand the error.

Comment: Print the model summary and observe how the output shape of each layer changes.

Comment: I think the problem is that you stack too many `Pooling` layers. If you start with input size `128`, you get sizes 128->63->30->14->6->2->1 for 6 `Conv2D` and `Pooling` layers (which you get with depth 5, because you add one additional layer before the loop). After that, you can't make the image smaller, you are already at size `1` (which is most likely already too small).